# How do I get rid of the space at the bottom of the grid elements?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have this layout made with CSS grid.

[image]

It's adding extra space at the bottom of each element. I'd like the red background(grid cell) to take up the minimum height of it's content.

Something like:

`grid-template-rows: <minimum height> <minimum height> <minimum height>;`

How do I acheive this?

I know I can just change the HTML and make it easier but since the title comes first on smaller screens, I can't change the structure.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "image image title"
                       "image image desc-1"
                       "image image desc-2";
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  background: tomato;
}
.title {
  grid-area: title;
}
.image {
  grid-area: image;
}
.desc-1 {
  grid-area: desc-1;
}
.desc-2 {
  grid-area: desc-2;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
}
.title, .desc-1, .desc-2 {
  margin-block: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h2 class="item title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" />
  </div>
  <p class="item desc-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p class="item desc-2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 4 rows instead of 3. You can also simplify your code like below:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr; /* size of columns */
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.item {
  background: tomato;
}
.image {
  grid-row: 1/span 4; /* placed at 1st row and takes 4 rows */
  grid-column: 1; /* places at 1st column */
}
.image img {
  display: block;
}
.title, .desc-1, .desc-2 {
  margin-block: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <h2 class="item title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" />
  </div>
  <p class="item desc-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p class="item desc-2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`grid-auto-rows`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-auto-rows.php) property.

here you can set size of your rows. But since you can't set it to auto because it also based in image. You can set size depending what height corresponds to your min-content.

Here I set the size to 25px and 20px per row respectively.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "image image title"
        "image image desc-1"
        "image image desc-2";
    gap: 1rem;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-auto-rows: 25px 20px;
}

.item {
    background: tomato;
}
.title {
    grid-area: title;
    height:  fit-content;
}
.image {
    grid-area: image;
}
.desc-1 {
    grid-area: desc-1;
    height:  fit-content;
}
.desc-2 {
    grid-area: desc-2;
    height:  fit-content;
}

.image img {
    display: block;
}
.title,
.desc-1,
.desc-2 {
    margin-block: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
      <h2 class="item title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg" />
      </div>
      <p class="item desc-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      <p class="item desc-2">Sed ut perspiciatis unde.</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: the gaps are not increasing. you are placing each text in each cell of the grid but since you want the background in its min-height thus i looks wide in height gap. May try placing them in one cell if that's what you mean.

Comment: look at my edit if that's that's correct. you can adjust the justify content property

Comment: The problem is I can't change the HTML structure as it has a different layout on smaller screens.

Comment: Again, I adjusted my answer. Hopes it really helps finally :)

Comment: Thanks, but this wouldn't work as my content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but you can add `align-items: start` to your container, which aligns your grid items inside a cell along the blocs.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "image image title"
                       "image image desc-1"
                       "image image desc-2";
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: start; 
}
```

You can also use the `align-self` on child elements if you don't want to apply it to all children.

[image]

Update:
If you want to have an equal amount of gap between your elements, then you can set the height of the image to zero:

```
.image {
  grid-area: image;
  height: 0;
}
```

[image]

Although, it will be better to restructure your HTML so put your right items in a new flex/grid container to avoid the image overflowing the container.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure? check https://codepen.io/martinmoose/pen/QWxKPYz

Comment: It's not what I'm looking for. I also want the gaps to stay the same,i.e, `1rem`.

Comment: What about just setting the height of your image to zero then?